# filtering lines using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file containing personal data from people.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
FN:Rene van der Harten
N:van der Harten;Rene;J.;Sir;R.D.O.N.
SORT-STRING:Harten
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
FN:Robert Pau Shou Chang
N:Pau;Shou Chang;Robert
SORT-STRING:Pau
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
FN:Osamu Koura
N:Koura;Osamu
SORT-STRING:Koura
END:VCARD
```

I wanted to sort only the last name alphabetically. I've tried

```
grep N: <filename>
```

to filter the lines begin with N:, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `I wanted to sort` sorting is different than filtering

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things, as you can see:

```
grep "^N\:" test.txt | sort -t ":" -k 2
```

First, you filter on lines, starting with `N:`:

```
^N : means that the line must start with capital 'N'
\: : means that next to that first 'N' you must have a semicolon.
     The backslash is meant to explain to "grep" this is not a range separator
```

Second, you sort on the second column:

```
-t ":" : means that the semicolon is the fields separator
-k 2   : means you need to sort on the second column
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that grep will try to match anywhere in each line and not just from the beginning, making `N:` match all lines that contains `N:` You can use the anchor `^` to anchor the pattern to the start of the line:

```
$ grep '^N:' <filename>
```

If you only want to extract the text between the first `:` and the first `;` then you might want to opt for AWK:

```
$ awk -F'[;:]' ' $1 == "N" { print $2 }' <filename> 
van der Harten
Pau
Koura
```

The way it works is that AWK will split the input string into fields, and the option `-F` specifies that the fields will be splitted by `:` and `;`. Making the first field (`$1`) equal `N` and the second the last name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that you want `N:` at the start of the line:

```
grep ^N: <filename>
```